# How can i capture the download progress in chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension which moniters the download progress. I am able the capture the download begin and download complete events but have no idea on how to get the changed progress? Please help.
Below is my download listener

```
function AddDownloadListener() {
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(DownloadCreated);
    chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(DownloadChanged);



    function DownloadCreated(el) {
        console.log("Download Begins");
        console.log(el);
        mobjPortToFoxtrot.postMessage({ message: "Download Begins", element: el });
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        function DownloadChanged(el) {
        if (el.danger === undefined || el.danger == null) {
            console.log(el.state.current);
            mobjPortToFoxtrot.postMessage({ message: el.state.current, element: el });
        }
        else {
            console.log("dangerous content");
            mobjPortToFoxtrot.postMessage({ message: "dangerous content", element: el });
        }
        console.log(el);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to poll for the download status.

Comment: @RobW : Any reference of the similar thing? how can i poll for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do so in an event-based way.

From [`onChanged` documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onChanged) (emphasis mine):

> When any of a `DownloadItem`'s properties **except `bytesReceived` and `estimatedEndTime`** changes, this event fires with the `downloadId` and an object containing the properties that changed.

This means Chrome will not fire events for the download progress, which kind of makes sense: this changes very frequently, you don't want an event fired after every network packet.

It's up to you to query the progress with a sensible rate (i.e. every second while there is an active download) with something like this:

```
// Query the proportion of the already downloaded part of the file
// Passes a ratio between 0 and 1 (or -1 if unknown) to the callback
function getProgress(downloadId, callback) {
  chrome.downloads.search({id: downloadId}, function(item) {
    if(item.totalBytes > 0) {
      callback(item.bytesReceived / item.totalBytes);
    } else {
      callback(-1);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks fot the answer, it make sense. thinking of doing it in setInterval. how good it is to use setInterval() in chrome extension?

Comment: @Shiv That's actually a tricky question: it does not work in general with `"persistent": false` background pages, but a short interval should work (so that Chrome doesn't consider the extension idle). Make sure to carefully manage it so you only poll while there are active downloads and test that part thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, need to check it

Comment: A little weird that there's `onCreated` event but no `onFinished` event when downloading is finished.

Comment: @KulaGGin Maybe, but it's pretty easy to emulate one with `onChanged` with appropriate filtering (`state` changes to `"complete"`)