# JS - download complete trigger for interaction with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, download

I have a situation where i want the client to download resources that the node server will send to it.

Node will send the data through ejs templates. The data will be a link.
The client will auto download that link.

Then node server will send the next element in order to be downloaded. All that in a loop until no more links for download are left, adn they are all downloaded from the client.

The problem is how the node server will know that the resource has been downloaded from the client - in order to dynamically inject the next link element to be downloaded?

I was about to ask if is there a js signal, after a succesful download, to send it back to the server, that will trigger the server to send the client the next element through ejs templates.

Then i came across this post:
[Browser event when downloaded file is saved to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343418/browser-event-when-downloaded-file-is-saved-to-disk)

I found out that there is no such signal.

Yet isn't there a workaround to achieve this functionality?

Maybe some websockets extention?

Comment: There is no workaround. Suggest you zip all the files and make one download

Comment: Look a tthis. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179686/how-can-i-capture-the-download-progress-in-chrome-extension

Comment: Isn;t there a way to work around it by having js monitor net activity?

Comment: Not from within a page window...no.